# where is the oracle 12c logfile?

Tags: oracle

I am getting all of the following error first:

> ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

When I export the ORACLE_SID , I can run any command and I get the following error:

> connected to an idle instance

Where is the ALERTLOG file in 12C?

I can't see any file in ORACLE_HOME/log folder. I am using ubuntu 14.04 BTW.

Comment: I think the question is useful in terms of "where is the log file". But the sub-question about the idle instance should just be removed from this question to improve the quality, no?

Answer (score 9):

The alert log never has been under `ORACLE_HOME/log`.

It is in `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<sid>/<sid>/trace` and is named `alert_<sid>.log`

If you don't have `$ORACLE_BASE`, this typically is equivalent to `$ORACLE_HOME/../../..`

This is no different in 12c than it was in 11g (or 10g if I recall correctly).

You can also use the ADRCI tool: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/adrci.htm#SUTIL1474

Comment: thanks , I have resolved the error by allocating more memory in sysctl.conf file , Now I can login to the commandline sql , but I cant login to the web EM though , I am posting another question here , can you please help ?

Comment: ADRC tool for 12cR2:   https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-adr-command-interpreter-adrci.html#GUID-41EE7D7F-BF4A-471F-91B7-C91596101DF7

Answer (score 4):

alert log find better way;------

**step 1**

```
select * from v$diag_info;
```

**step 2**

```
$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<sid>/<sid>/trace and is named alert_<sid>.log
```

or

```
desc v$diag_info



Name                                                                Null?    Type
 ------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
 INST_ID                                                                      NUMBER
 NAME                                                                         VARCHAR2(64)
 VALUE                                                                        VARCHAR2(512)
 CON_ID                                                                       NUMBER
```

**Quick sql*plus script to get it out**

```
-- diag_info
-- quick check of the new v$diag_info view that came in with 11
col inst_id form 9999 head inst
col name form a25
col value form a60 wrap
spool diag_info.lst
set lines 120
select * from v$diag_info
order by name
/
spool off

INST_ID NAME                 VALUE                                                            CON_ID
-------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------
       1 Diag Enabled          TRUE                                                                  0
       1 ADR Base              D:\APP\ORACLE                                                         0
       1 ADR Home              D:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122                                0
       1 Diag Trace            D:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122\trace                          0
       1 Diag Alert            D:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122\alert                          0
       1 Diag Incident         D:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122\incident                       0
       1 Diag Cdump            D:\app\oracle\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122\cdump                          0
       1 Health Monitor        D:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122\hm                             0
       1 Default Trace File    D:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\ora122\ora122\trace\ora122_ora_7416.trc      0
       1 Active Problem Count  0                                                                     0
       1 Active Incident Count 0                                                                     0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    show parameter background;
```

will provide you path for alert log file.